# Why is macOS Monterey (12.0.1) showing me 3 different command line tools updates, infinitely?

Tags: macos, software-update

[image: screen shot of software update]

My new MacBook Pro (Apple Silicon) is showing me 3 updates available for Command Line Tools. I don’t have Xcode installed. When I run these updates, it appears to succeed, but then Software Update shows all 3 available again.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: A nearly identical problem plagued me for a while on macOS Ventura 13.0 for a couple weeks, btw

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with Final Cut Pro. If you click "More Info…", there should be a list of updates. Try selecting only one and update it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually did try this to no avail several days ago. However, today, Monday, December 13, 2021, I opened the Software Update prefpane to discover that the three CLT updates were replaced by just one newer update: CLT for Xcode 13.2.   Perhaps this was an Apple-side glitch for which they pushed a fix today.